# How to improve performance of a select statement, which calculates a running total

Tags: sql, performance, firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using Firebird 2.5.2 and am trying to figure out, how to improve performance of a select statement, which calculates a running total. Here is the situation:

A table "PAYMENTS" (simplified for a better overview)

```
CREATE TABLE PAYMENTS 
(
  ID                    INTEGER             NOT NULL,
  PAYMENT_TYPE          SMALLINT            DEFAULT 0,
  BANKING_ACCOUNTID     INTEGER             DEFAULT -100,
  AMOUNT                DOUBLE PRECISION,
  CALCAMOUNT            DOUBLE PRECISION,
  PAYMENT_DATE          TIMESTAMP
);

ALTER TABLE PAYMENTS ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PAYMENTS PRIMARY KEY (ID);
CREATE GENERATOR PAYMENTS_PRIMARYKEY;

CREATE ASC INDEX PAYMENTS_AMOUNT ON PAYMENTS (AMOUNT);
CREATE ASC INDEX PAYMENTS_BANKACCOUNT ON PAYMENTS (BANKING_ACCOUNTID);
CREATE ASC INDEX PAYMENTS_BDATE ON PAYMENTS (PAYMENT_DATE);

ALTER TABLE PAYMENTS ADD CONSTRAINT FK_PAYM_BANKING_ACCOUNTID FOREIGN KEY (BANKING_ACCOUNTID) REFERENCES BANKINGACCOUNTS (ID) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET DEFAULT;
```

The value in "AMOUNT" is always positive. Whether it's an incoming or outgoing payment, is defined via "PAYMENT_TYPE". Both determine the value in "CALCAMOUNT", i.e. for calculation reasons the value here is either "-100" or "100".

A stored procedure to calculate the sum:

```
SET TERM  ^^ ;
create procedure SP_BALANCE_FOR_DATE_AND_BANKID (PAYMENT_DATE timestamp, BANKING_ACCOUNTID integer) returns (BALANCE double precision)
as
declare variable TempAmount double precision;
begin
    TempAmount = 0;
 
    select sum(CALCAMOUNT) as SUMME from PAYMENTS where (PAYMENT_DATE < :PAYMENT_DATE) and (BANKING_ACCOUNTID = :BANKING_ACCOUNTID) into TempAmount;
    if (TempAmount is null) then TempAmount = 0;
     
    BALANCE = TempAmount;
    
    suspend;
end
 ^^
SET TERM ;  ^^
```

The actual select statement:

```
select PAYMENTS.*,
case when PAYMENT_TYPE = 1 then ((select BALANCE from SP_BALANCE_FOR_DATE_AND_BANKID(PAYMENT_DATE, BANKING_ACCOUNTID)) + AMOUNT)
else ((select BALANCE from SP_BALANCE_FOR_DATE_AND_BANKID(PAYMENT_DATE, BANKING_ACCOUNTID)) - AMOUNT) end
as CURRENTBALANCE
from PAYMENTS
where (ID > 0) and (BANKING_ACCOUNTID = :BANKING_ACCOUNTID) and ((PAYMENT_TYPE = 1) or (PAYMENT_TYPE = 2)) and (PAYMENT_DATE >= '01.11.2021') and (PAYMENT_DATE <= '30.11.2021 23:59:59')
order by PAYMENT_DATE
```

The user can define the bank account and the date range and the results are being showed in a grid, where additionally to all fields from "PAYMENTS" the field "CURRENTBALANCE" is being displayed, which shows the balance / the total at the time *after* the appropriate payment. Regardless of the defined date range for the records to display, *all* records before a record (based on PAYMENT_DATE) have to be counted for that record.

The problem: it's very slow, the more records exist.

I've searched prior to posting here and saw the following solutions:

- Same as mine, but without the stored procedure, i.e. with a subquery within the select statement
- A query with self-joined PAYMENTS table
- A query using analytic functions

The performance of the first two is about the same, i.e. very slow. Before testing, I had tried to add more indexes too.

The third one is possible with Firebird 3.0 only, apparently. Since I'm on Firebird 2.5 still, I would like to ask, how I could improve the performance of my select statement?

There is of course the option to store the appropriate total with each record directly once it's being stored, but the problem here is, that once a payments gets deleted or modified, the total of all records after the deleted / modified one becomes incorrect.

Comment: Make intermediate able, where you would keep totals per-month, per-year, per-week, per-decade - depending upon how many data you have. Only make totals from individual records on the date after the last "closed" period,

Comment: Please show the query plan. Also, why are you using 2.5.2? That is a very old version with known security issues. The latest 2.5 is 2.5.9, and the latest overall is 4.0.0.

Comment: In any case, using a stored procedure for this doesn't make a lot of sense to me, and it is probably one of the reasons why it is so slow. Upgrading to 3.0.x or 4.0.x and using window functions (introduced in 3.0) would likely make it more performant

Comment: @Arioch'The I know it's common to have such "closed" periods in similar applications, but it means some restrictions in the daily usage. Since I always try to offer the user as much flexibility as possible, I was avoiding such "closed" periods so far.If nothing help, I might need to switch to an intermediate table, but maybe rather one that stores the balance for each payment only and after update / deletion a trigger could update affected "follow up" records.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel 
Good question about Firebird upgrade. It appears like something "major" to me, which would require a lot of testing etc. and so could be an option for the next major release of my application. The current issue exists in the current version though, which is only maintained by bug fixing, so to speak. FB upgrade here would be problematical and delay the work on the next release. That's the thoughts so far, at least...

Comment: @MarkRotteveel
As for the current situation: the query plan is
`PLAN (PAYMENTS INDEX (PAYMENTS_BDATE, FK_PAYM_BANKING_ACCOUNTID))
PLAN (PAYMENTS INDEX (PAYMENTS_BDATE, FK_PAYM_BANKING_ACCOUNTID))
PLAN (PAYMENTS ORDER PAYMENTS_BDATE INDEX (PAYMENTS_BDATE, PK_PAYMENTS))`

The reason for the stored procedure is, that it is being used in one more place, where only balance for a certain payment record is needed. But I had tried the self join alternative without using the stored procedure as well and the duration was about the same + plus there were some differences in the results.

Comment: @PatrickMarten make the program automatically "re-open" those period and "invalidate cache". Also, flexibility to user is not always good, it sometimes is bad, like original C language which did not checked datatypes of variables. Freedom, yes, but more like freedom to do mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put whole your query into the stored procedure calculating and returning running total in a simple loop. It will be the fastest way.

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE RUNNING_BALANCE(BIGINT ACCOUNTID, DATE_BEGIN DATE, DATE_END DATE)
RETURNS (BALANCE DOUBLE PRECISION)
AS
DECLARE t SMALLINT;
DECLARE a DOUBLE PRECISION;
BEGIN
 BALANCE = 0;

 select sum(CALCAMOUNT) from PAYMENTS
  where (PAYMENT_DATE < :DATE_BEGIN)
   and (BANKING_ACCOUNTID = :ACCOUNTID)
  into :BALANCE;

 FOR select PAYMENT_TYPE, AMOUNT from PAYMENTS
   where (ID > 0)
    and (BANKING_ACCOUNTID = :ACCOUNTID)
    and ((PAYMENT_TYPE = 1) or (PAYMENT_TYPE = 2))
    and (PAYMENT_DATE >= :DATE_BEGIN)
    and (PAYMENT_DATE < :DATE_END + 1)
   order by PAYMENT_DATE
  INTO :t, :a DO
  BEGIN
   IF (t = 1) THEN
     BALANCE = BALANCE + a;
   ELSE
     BALANCE = BALANCE - a;
   SUSPEND;
  END
END
```

Comment: I've tried this now, but the duration is still the same. The "problem" is, that I can't track the latest balance and add the current amount per iteration, because the resulting records are not (always) the same as the records relevant for the calculation of the balance. I.e. the balance has to be calculated for all records prior to the current one, regardless of their visibility in the resulting records that are returned by the stored procedure. Either there isn't any other way or I'm not seeing the forest for the trees.

Comment: Hm, what about CTE inside a stored procedure? Looks like it's possible in general, but going by the syntax, it would be in the `for loop` like the `select` part. Does it mean, it would be executed for each record?

Comment: One query in the beginning to calculate initial balance at the first visible record and then the loop through visible records adding/subtracting their amount to current balance.

Comment: It's sometimes that easy... Thank you very much! For the current situation that's quite an improvement. One question to make sure I'm doing it right: What is the correct way to determine, whether it's the first iteration of a `for loop`? Currently I'm using a variable for this. If it's value is null, I'm setting it to 0 and only calculate the prior balance in this one case. Is there a better way, i.e. something like an built-in counter or so?

Comment: Use a separate query before FOR. @Patrik

Comment: I had tried this first, but it wasn't working in the first attempt, so I moved it inside the for loop. Then I figured out what was wrong in the first attempt - I mixed up the parameters... Modified it and it works. Thanks again!